# How I can solve npm installtion problem to laravel project

Tags: laravel, npm-install, laravel-7, npm-publish, npm-request

when i run ***npm i*** it returns the error.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\personal\freshShop>npm i
**
npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...3ec2605d1fc435f4d8651' **

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Najmun_Nafiz\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-06-04T02_02_30_082Z-debug.log
```

[image]

Comment: Please open this screenshot image and than please someone give me answer.

Comment: could you provide your **package.json** contents ?

Comment: "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "core-js": "^3.6.5",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "vform": "^1.0.1",
        "vue-router": "^3.3.2"
    }

Answer (score 0):

Delete `node_modules`, 'package-lock.json' and clean your npm cache via:
`npm cache clean --force`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exact issue by upgrading my NodeJS version to 14.x.